# Bash, find and delete whilst retaining directory

Tags: unix

I am trying my hand at some Bash scripting and any help would be appreciated.

The script is supposed to find all users users in /Users/ and delete everything inside. Movies, Documents, Desktop and Music.

Whilst still retaining the directory essentially emptying it. Also excluding the user files of ladmin, shared and Guest.

When I execute. It doesn't empty the files though I get the feed back I would expect. Am I missing something simple here?

```
DIR_CD=/Users/

cd $DIR_CD

find . -type d ! -name "*ladmin*" ! -name "*Guest*" ! -name "*Shared*" \
       -maxdepth 1 -print -exec rm -rf {}/Desktop/* \;
find . -type d ! -name "*ladmin*" ! -name "*Guest*" ! -name "*Shared*" \
       -maxdepth 1 -print -exec rm -rf {}/Documents/* \;
find . -type d ! -name "*ladmin*" ! -name "*Guest*" ! -name "*Shared*" \
       -maxdepth 1 -print -exec rm -rf {}/Movies/* \;
find . -type d ! -name "*ladmin*" ! -name "*Guest*" ! -name "*Shared*" \
       -maxdepth 1 -print -exec rm -rf {}/Music/* \;
```

Comment: This does not sound like a good beginner project. I hope you are testing on someone else's system!

Comment: Assuming ladmin, Guest and Shared exist in /Users that looks good to me. Any errors? Did you run with sudo?

Comment: They exist, but it would seem that other users files still seem to stay in tact.

Comment: Also I am in an environment where I can test with no risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
for d in /Users/*; do
    case ${d#*/} in ladmin | Guest | Shared ) continue ;; esac
    rm -rf "$d"/Desktop/* "$d"/Documents/* "$d"/Movies/* "$d"/Music/*
done
```

With Bash [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) you could do it all with a single wildcard expression.

Comment: No this deletes everything in the ladmin shared and Guest.